# ZeroMQ How can server mantain connections with all clients?

Tags: c++, multithreading, zeromq

I have the following task:

Clients connect to a server on 1 port (e.g. 8080). The server should remember them and after completing calculation it should send results to the clients. After that server gets some results again and again sends it to all clients. And so on.

How can server mantain connections with all clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found some code uses PUB\SUB model and works with NAT here http://grokbase.com/t/zeromq/zeromq-dev/112q9934vg/nat-firewall-pub-sub-traversal:

Publisher that connects, rather than binds:

```
import zmq
ctxt = zmq.Context()
pub = ctxt.socket(zmq.PUB)
pub.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:2000")
while 1:
pub.send(os.urandom(5))
```

Subscriber that binds, rather than connects:

```
import zmq
ctxt = zmq.Context()
sub = ctxt.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:2000")
while 1:
sub.rcv()
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need to maintain all connections from clients? I think, that "publish/subscribe" messaging model will satisfy described conditions. The server should "publish" results and clients should "subscribe" on this updates. Simplest example for such "server" you can find in zguide code samples: [wuserver.cpp](https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C++/wuserver.cpp)

Comment: I considered PUP\SUB pattern, but my server and clients can sit at different networks\behind NAT. I think the most robust solution is connection should be initiated by client.

Comment: I don't see problems with different networks etc, using pub/sub you need just set special connection type when connecting to the socket. So no changes from "robust" point of view.

Comment: Could you provide more information about "special connection type"? I guess I have to get PUB\SUB proxy between all networks there are clients.